# CMAKE: how to include and link Lua 5.1 lib?

Tags: c, macos, lua, cmake

I'm super new to CMake, and for now it all looks like black magic to me.
Example that I token is from [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html)!
How to properly include Lua(5.1) lib and link it with CMake?

Sample works when compiled by hands as in

**$gcc -W -Wall -g -o main main.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1 -llua**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

int main(void) {
    puts("lua interpretor:");
    char buff[256];
    int error;

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate(); /* opens Lua */
    luaL_openlibs(L); /* opens the standard libraries */

    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL) {
        error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, buff, strlen(buff), "line") ||
                lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
        if (error) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
            lua_pop(L, 1); /* pop error message from the stack */
        }
    }
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

current CMakeList.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

and err.log

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_luaL_loadbufferx", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_luaL_newstate", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_luaL_openlibs", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_lua_close", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_lua_pcallk", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_lua_settop", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_lua_tolstring", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
```

Comment: You tagged your question as a C++ one but it terribly looks like a C code. Further you're compiling with gcc and not g++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't linked the Lua library to the executable. This is done using `target_link_libraries()`. You'll need to locate or specify the location of the library first though. Luckily for you, Lua ships with [a cmake script](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua/blob/master/cmake/FindLua.cmake) for finding Lua.

```
project(test)

find_package(Lua51 REQUIRED)

include_directories(/usr/local/include ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(test ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thank you! I will continue with learning about c and c++ compilers, and CMake! This helped a lot